# Change the contents of the array

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer

I'm very confused how to turn it into an asterisk(*) symbol

**Inputs in array:**

```
array = [12345, 12354, 12334]
```

**Outputs in array:**

```
['123**', '123**', '123**']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to cast to string followed by string splicing then [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to fill the missing values based on length.

```
input_ = [12345, 12354, 12334]

[i[:3].ljust(len(i), "*") for i in map(str, input_)]
```

---

```
['123**', '123**', '123**']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `zip` twice with `set`:

```
s = [12345, 12354, 12334]
r = [[i if len(set(b)) == 1 else '*' for i in b] for b in zip(*map(str, s))]
result = list(map(''.join, zip(*r)))
```

Output

```
['123**', '123**', '123**']
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand the task, so I suppose it's asking to turn the last two digits into asterisks.
In order to do so, you have to turn the elements into strings.

```
[str(n)[:-2]+"**" for n in list]
```

This will cut off the last two digits of the number.